# How to get Pre Post Metrics from Facebook Insights API in ASp.net c#?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook

I have to show the status of my Face book Page such as No of total likes, total comments on a web Application.
So, can any one help me to know--

How to get Pre Post Metrics from Facebook Insights API in ASp.net c#?

Thanks in Advance